# Baked normal map is partly distorted/flipped

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake a normal map from high res model onto a low res one. Normals are all okay, no modifiers, no double vertices. Result is the same when baking the map in xNormal. Result is the same when I scaled them in edit mode about 2x bigger. Changing the ray distance doesn't change anything than that the distorted part becomes green.

[image]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A0C87Pm-Pzau8YMuoi_qU40vibCMlLBc/view?usp=sharing

I'm super sorry, it was way too big even in zip form when I tried to download it there but here it is in drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your file. The "Ray distance" is too high. With 0.01m it worked fine for me.

Comment: yes it works for me too